# Unable to get two way binding to work with a <UL> and an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to bind a `<ul>` element to a property that is an `observableArray`. The `<ul>` does get bound when the view model already has some entries in the array. But when i dynamically add entries to the property it does not update the UI.

I created an example at: http://jsfiddle.net/shardul/SZWPT/

I'm just getting started with Knockout and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/SZWPT/3/

The line I corrected was:

```
this.nameList.push(this.nameToAdd());
```

When you were doing `this.nameList().push` you were manipulating the array inside the observableArray, which does *not* automatically notify listeners of changes.  By pushing to the observableArray itself listeners are immediately notified and the UI will refresh.